# google cloud platform does not render static website pages in sub directories

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I recently migrated my static website to Google Cloud : www.vizitdata.com.  Any page that is in the root folder renders.  However, I have created a sub directory called "Cubs" and none of the html pages render in this directory.  I am redirected to GoDaddy where my domain is hosted.  This makes me think that Google Cloud is interpreting my sub directory as a subdomain.  Is this assumption correct?

And is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you saying that a link like "http://www.vizidata.com/directory/file.html" doesn't render correctly, or are you trying to link to just the directory, like "http://www.vizidata.com/directory/"?

Comment: I figured this one out.  I'm guessing I need to do something in GoDaddy to recognize vizitdata.com (without the www) because once I added the "www" the page resolved.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out. I'm guessing I need to do something in GoDaddy to recognize vizitdata.com (without the www) because once I added the "www" the page resolved. Cheers